# Passing a default value as a parameter to a web service call in react application

Tags: reactjs

I will like to be able to pass in a default_pageable.page.size as the first parameter
in the api call below. How can I achieve that? This is not working

```
     Promise.all([
              api.solutionForms.search({
                  pageable: DEFAULT_PAGEABLE.page.size = 7//This is not working. I want a default value of 7,
                  statuses: [SolutionFormStatus.APPROVAL_REQUIRED.name]
              }),
          ]).then(values => {
              const [
                  solutionformsRequiringAction
              ] = values;

              this.setState({
                  loading: false,
                  solutionformsRequiringAction: solutionformsRequiringAction.data
              });
          });



        const DEFAULT_PAGEABLE = {
          page: {
            size: null,
            number: null,
          },
          sortBy: {
            name: null,
            direction: null
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a default value in that way, that's a syntax error. If you want to default to a value you can use an expression like this:

```
Promise.all([
              api.solutionForms.search({
                  // If DEFAULT_PAGEABLE.page.size is a falsy value (such as null, 0, undefined), 
                  // the expression will evaluate to 7, otherwise it will evaulate to 
                  // whatever DEFAULT_PAGEABLE.page.size contains
                  pageable: DEFAULT_PAGEABLE.page.size || 7,
                  statuses: [SolutionFormStatus.APPROVAL_REQUIRED.name]
              }),
          ]).then(values => {
              const [
                  solutionformsRequiringAction
              ] = values;

              this.setState({
                  loading: false,
                  solutionformsRequiringAction: solutionformsRequiringAction.data
              });
          });



        const DEFAULT_PAGEABLE = {
          page: {
            size: null,
            number: null,
          },
          sortBy: {
            name: null,
            direction: null
          }
        };
```

Comment: I tried your solution and getting the same error. It is not working

Comment: Looks like `DEFAULT_PAGEABLE.page.number` is undefined when you're using it. 1) in your sample code you're not using number, and 2) try declaring DEFAULT_PAGEABLE before using it in your promise chain

Comment: Declare === `const DEFAULT_PAGEABLE`, initlaiize === `const DEFAULT_PAGEABLE = {...}`. Move the initialization before the Promise.all